# How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for dialogflow nodejs sdk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to use google's dialogflow library for node.js and i'm following this tutorial but got this error :

```
(node:25452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.<anonymous> (D:\WORK\chatbot-app-master\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:167:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\WORK\chatbot-app-master\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:19:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:25452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without
a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25452) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I did the exact same thing as in the tutorial and did the 
`set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=d:\WORK\chat-bot-test-project-277213-8aee1b1e894b.json`
and didn't work i even added it to the environment variables in windows and still not working when i hit the api.
Here's my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const structjson = require('./structjson.js');
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const uuid = require('uuid');

const config = require('../config/keys');

const projectId = config.googleProjectID
const sessionId = config.dialogFlowSessionID
const languageCode = config.dialogFlowSessionLanguageCode


// Create a new session
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

// We will make two routes 


// Text Query Route

router.post('/textQuery', async (req, res) => {
    //We need to send some information that comes from the client to Dialogflow API 
    // The text query request.
    console.log(projectId)
    const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
                text: req.body.text,
                // The language used by the client (en-US)
                languageCode: languageCode,
            },
        },
    };

    // Send request and log result
    const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
    console.log('Detected intent');
    const result = responses[0].queryResult;
    console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
    console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);

    res.send(result)
})
```

what can i do at this point ?

Comment: check out this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-credentials-helper may help you

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root directory of your computer in your terminal and type GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=d:\WORK\chat-bot-test-project-277213-8aee1b1e894b.json